# How insert return caret and new line in bash?

Tags: bash, email, line

I need to send email by bash script:

```
$message=$line1$line2$line3$line

echo $message | mail -s "$subject" myname@somewhere.com
```

How insert end of lines so body of email I can see divided by rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using heredoc format;

```
mail -s "$subject" myname@example.com << MSG_BODY_HERE
$line1
$line2
$line3
$line4
MSG_BODY_HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
message="$(printf '%s\n' "$line1" "$line2" "$line3" "$line")

echo "$message" | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

use echo -e $message | mail

From echo manual:

-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Answer (score -1):

```
message="${line1}\n${line2}\n${line3}${line}\n"
```